# KDE 4 Strange Problem

Tags: 14.04, 14.10, kde, qt, kde4

A problem with KDE is really driving me crazy, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have a xunbuntu 14.04 on which I installed kde-plasma-desktop. There are very few styles (System settings -> Appication Appearance -> Styles) available, so I installed QtCurve, a fully customizable Theme/Style.

Well, after QtCurve installation, I experiance a strange behavior:
On every boot/reboot, KDE stile gets reset to the basic "GTK+ Style".
Note that this did not happen prior to the installation of QtCurve theme (by synaptic).

Now, my questions are, in order of importance:

1) How can I solve this problem.
2) Where I can find a log of packages installed along with QtCurve.
3) How can I find possible conflicts between installed packages.

Thanks A LOT.